# Restrictive Clause vs. Non Restrictive Clause

Tags: commas, clauses, non-restrictive

Consider the following example:

To add to the confusion, every New Year's Day a **person, according** to this Korean counting system, becomes a year older, regardless of his or her actual birthday.

This clause is restrictive as "his or her" refers to "person". So, then why is there a comma?

Comment: The comma is not required. Regardless modifies becomes, not person, because *becoming older disregards* the actual brthday.

Comment: You seem to think that if "his" appears in a clause, the clause is restrictive. Why?

Comment: The classic sentence is "I read the New York Times, which prints all the news that's fit to print."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove *", according to this Korean counting system, "* without changing the meaning of the sentence. A non-essential element like this is always surrounded in commas.

*"His or her"* doesn't have anything to do with the placement of that comma.

See below:

*To add to the confusion, every New Year's Day a person becomes a year older, regardless of his or her actual birthday.*

https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/05/

Comment: Oh, I did not even notice that that was nonessential.